# Extend or override type definition for vuex store

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vuex for state management in my app and I'm also using TypeScript, ideally I like to be able to refer to a strongly typed version of the store rather than just the default where state is 'any' etc... I know how to 'extend' type definitions to add for example a new property, but I'm struggling to figure out a way (if possible) to 'force' a strongly typed store definition over the default Store. I'm just getting errors saying that subsequent definitions must have the same type, which I guess is understandable, but I'm lazy and want some intellisense! ;-)

Most of the docs I've read say its not possible to override a type already defined in a type definition file and that you can only add additional properties for example, but is there any way what I'm after is possible this way or any other? Otherwise I'm going to have to remember all the names of my methods/actions etc..

Comment: If you are coming across this and you don't want to wrap the store in another function, there is another way that just works with the type system
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139966/vuex-store-type-with-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can't redefine an existing property, you can defined a typed version of the `$store` property as an alias for the un-typed version:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import * as Vuex from 'vuex'

declare module "vue/types/vue" {
    interface Vue {
        $typedStore: Vuex.Store<{
            count: number
        }>;
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "$storeTyped", {
    get: function(this: Vue) {
        return this.$store;
    }
})


const App = new Vue({
    computed: {
        counter: function (this: Vue) {
            return this.$storeTyped.state.count; // Works and is typed
        }
    },
    // Other stuff
});
```

Comment: I think you swapped from `$typedStore` to `$storeTyped` part way through

Comment: If you are coming across this and you don't want to wrap the store in another function, there is another way that just works with the type system
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139966/vuex-store-type-with-typescript

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but I hope I help someone in some way. I actually got to do this solution after looking at Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer. I only just wanted to force Vuex to allow only actions I defined. I believe I have found a way, specifically for the part where you said '*Otherwise I'm going to have to remember all the names of my **methods/actions***' and in my case with special emphasis on the actions part. I have not thoroughly tested this but so far it seems to work without problems.

Let's say you have code like below where you want to store people and cars in the Vuex store and only want to allow the actions for storing people and cars. For simplicity I removed a lot from the code and placed it all in one file.

An obvious problem would be that this might work only for the version of Vuex I use but I don't know, I have not tested that far. But obviously if the definitions of Dispatch and the Store constructor change the code might have to be changed as well.

### Node, the the code was tested on typescript 3.5.3, vue 2.6.10, and  vuex 3.1.2

```
import * as Vuex from 'vuex';

/** let's assume we have */
type Person = { name: string, age: number };
type Car = { make: string, year_made: number };

/** let us also assume we want to only allow these 2 actions */
enum ALLOWED_ACTIONS {
    STORE_CARS = 'actionStoreCars',
    STORE_PEOPLE = 'actionStorePeople'
}

/** 
 * defining a condition type that can be either 
 * an array or people or an array of cars 
 * */
export type Entities<T> = T extends Person | Car ? T[] : unknown;




/**
 * extending Vuex's dispatch function so that it will only allow
 * - The actions defined in the enum ALLOWED_ACTIONS
 * - A payload that is ONLY either of 
 *      > Person[]
 *      > Car[]
 * that is, we create a new dispatch that only allows actions that will result 
 * in the storage of either array of Persons or array of Cars only, nothing else.
 */
export interface Dispatch {
    /** If actions is ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_CARS then only allow payload of type Entities<Car> */
    (   action: ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_CARS , 
        payload: Entities<Car>, 
        options?: Vuex.DispatchOptions ): Promise<any>;


    /** If actions is ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_PEOPLE then only allow payload of type Entities<Person> */
    (   action: ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_PEOPLE , 
        payload: Entities<Person>, 
        options?: Vuex.DispatchOptions ): Promise<any>;

    /** this comes from the original definition of Dispatch */
    <P extends Vuex.Payload>(payloadWithType: P, options?: Vuex.DispatchOptions): Promise<any>;
}

/**
 * creating my own version of Vuex's store that uses the new defined dispatch above
 */
export class NewVuexStore extends Vuex.Store<any>  {
    dispatch: Dispatch;
    constructor(options: Vuex.StoreOptions<any>) {
        super(options);
        this.dispatch = Vuex.Store.prototype.dispatch;
    }
}
```

And then this is how you would implement the new store.

```
/** this would be in the index.ts from where your store is defined */
// export default new Vuex.Store({...} // I commented this out just to show where the new change is made in here
export default new NewVuexStore({...})
```

And then below is the implementation

```
/** 
 * this is just to give clarity for a quick check if the code works
 * */

 /** create your array of Cars */
const cars : Entities<Car> = [];
cars.push({make: 'aaa', year_made: 1994});
cars.push({make: 'bbb', year_made: 1995});
cars.push({make: 'ccc', year_made: 1996});

 /** create array of Persons */
const people : Entities<Person> = [];
people.push({name: 'Tom', age: 49});
people.push({name: 'Tim', age: 29});
people.push({name: 'Bob', age: 9});

/** store cars and people in the Vuex store
 * this dispatches will succeed
 */
store.dispatch(ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_CARS, cars);
store.dispatch(ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_PEOPLE, people);

/** these cause errors, even VS Codes underlines them with errors */
store.dispatch(ALLOWED_ACTIONS.STORE_PEOPLE, cars); // cannot store cars when you said you are storing people
store.dispatch('not_allowed', people);
store.dispatch('not_allowed', cars);
store.dispatch('not_allowed');
store.dispatch('');
```