# Vuex store type with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to get a Vuex store to be Typescript friendly. I'm building the store as explained [here](https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8). However, when I access `this.$store` from a component, the type is `Store<any>` .

I couldn't figure out how to change it so that it defaults to `Store<MyState>` without requiring a cast every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone comes across this - we got around this issue by redefining the type that the constructor returned -

```
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue'
import { Store } from 'vuex'
import { RootState } from '@/store/types'

abstract class VueStrongClass extends Vue {
    public $store!: Store<RootState>
}
const VueStrong = Vue as VueConstructor<VueStrongClass>;

export default VueStrong;
```

and then we just

```
export default VueStrong.extend({
    name: 'name',

    components: {
        componentA,
        componentB,
},
```

which lets us then use typing properly:

```
methods: {
sessionStarted(): Boolean | undefined {
    return this.$store.state.sessionState?.session.started;
},
```

Comment: do you know if there's a way to get typing to work with this.$store.getters?

Comment: @maembe Unfortunately I don't think so - you might be able to get real fancy with an enum and some generics, but that feels worse than just casting manually.  =\

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it is impossible to override the `Store<any>` type that is defined by the VueX types with a more specific type. The best I could come up with was to add a second field that returns `$store` but properly typed so you don't have to use casts everywhere or declare it in all your components:

```
import { Store } from "vuex";

// Type the $tstore properly, which is the same as $store but properly typed.
// Unfortunately you cannot override the Store<any> type.
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $tstore: Store<State>;
  }
}

// Set $tstore to be a getter that simply returns $store.
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "$tstore", {
  get: function() {
    return this.$store as Store<State>;
  },
  enumerable: true,
});
```

Comment: You can improve on this, when you add ```/** @deprecated Use $tstore instead! */ $store: Store<State>``` to the declaration. At least in my IntelliJ, every use of this.$store is then marked as deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a property in your component so typescript will apply typing. I use this for `$refs` all the time but it works for the `$store` too. You don't need to do anything with the property apart from marking it with ! operator to tell the transpiler that vue will set the variable for you.

```
$store!: Store<StoreStateType>;
```

Another alternative I use is to use the [MapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) or [MapGetters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) component helpers. They create the properties for you so you can use them in the template. Example:

```
@Component({
  computed: mapState({
    userFullName: (state: any) => state.user.fullName,
    userEmail: (state: any) => state.user.email
  })
})
```

Don't forget to import the Store, your vuex state class and any helper you use `import { Store, mapState } from "vuex";`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers satisfied me. I did some digging and found this little gem. Inside of my `store.ts` file, I merely add:

```js
declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>;
  }
}
```

So it looks more like this:

```js
//store.ts
import { createStore, Store } from "vuex";
import { CustomTool, CustomListType } from "custom";

export type State = {
  tool: CustomTool
  list: CustomListType | null
};

export default createStore({
  state: {
    tool: CustomTool.Empty
    list: null,
  } as State,
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {}
};

declare module "@vue/runtime-core" {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $store: Store<State>;
  }
}
```

Using vue3 and typescript 4.4.