# How is the correct way to work with Vuex and typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

So far, the only information I found about the topic was this [article](https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8).

I am trying to implement the store with 2 modules.

```
export interface RootState {
    /** root state props **/
}

const store: StoreOptions<RootState> = {
    modules: {
        foo,
        bar,
    },
};

export default new Vuex.Store<RootState>(store);
```

Then I have both modules:

```
export interface FooState {
    //(...)    
}

export const foo: Module<FooState, RootState> = {
    //(...)
};

export interface BarState {
    //(...)    
}

export const bar: Module<BarState, RootState> = {
    //(...)
};
```

All was ok until I had one situation where I needed a getter from foo module to access bar state:

```
export const getters: GetterTree<FooState, RootState> = {
    getInfo: (state, {}, rootState) => number {
        const value = rootState.bar.somevalue;
        //(...)
    },
};
```

I had a linting error explaining that rootState had no bar property. After some time thinking about it I managed to solve the error changing the original RootState interface:

```
export interface RootState {
    /** root state props **/
    foo: FooState;
    bar: BarState;
}
```

It solved the problem and was great for the IDE intellisense.

Is this aproach correct? To add all modules into the RootState interface used by StoreOptions?

Also, as it seems there is a lack of documentation about these typed interfaces (StoreOptions, Module, GetterTree, etc): Is Vuex mature enough to be used with typescript?

Edit: I forgot to mention: I still need to cast this.$store when acessing the store from a component (but could minimize it with [vuex-class](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class)). It seems there is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139966/vuex-store-type-with-typescript) opened about it without answers. I suppose there is no other solution to this until now, am I right?

Comment: To your edit, in the `vue-shim.d.ts` file (presuming you have one) just declare the $store as `Store<RootState>`.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have a shims-vue.d.ts but I think it is the same. I have no idea about how to change the store type there. Can you show me an example? The best I found until now was this workaround: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-typescript-and-vue-cli-strongly-typed-store/39925

Comment: @Ohgodwhy What is this file for? How to setup the store type?

Comment: with vuex4 you can access getters like this:
`this.$store.getters['YourSubModule/yourGetterName']`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833424/how-to-access-vuex-module-getters-and-mutations

Answer (score 34):

Vuex is perfectly compatible with typescript using these vuex imports:

```
import {GetterTree, MutationTree, ActionTree} from "vuex"
```

The example below shows the easiest and most complete way to use vuex in typescript.

Principal store file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { GetterTree, MutationTree, ActionTree } from "vuex"
import MySubModule from '@/store/submodule'

Vue.use(Vuex)

class State {
    userId: string | null = null;
}

const getters = <GetterTree<State, any>>{
};

const mutations = <MutationTree<State>>{
    setUserId(state, payload) {
        state.userId = payload;
    }
};

const actions = <ActionTree<State, any>>{
    fetchUserId(store) {
    }
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: new State(),
    mutations: mutations,
    actions: actions,
    modules: {
        subModuleName: MySubModule,
        //other submodules
    }
})
```

SubModule store file:

```
import { GetterTree, MutationTree, ActionTree } from "vuex"

class State {
}

const mutations = <MutationTree<State>>{
};

const actions = <ActionTree<State, any>>{
};

const MySubModule = {
    namespaced: true,
    state: new State(),
    mutations: mutations,
    actions: actions
};

export default MySubModule;
```

Hoping to help you !

Comment: This solution won't work if you access that exported instance provided by `export default new Vuex.Store({ ... })`.

`store.state.subModule` throws an error.

Comment: It works perfectly fine for my by using `$store.state.subModule`.

Comment: This example is incomplete.  You need to show how to actually use the Vuex store from a component.

Comment: why did you put `any` in place of RootState? the correct one should not be `GetterTree < State, RootState>` `ActionTree < State, RootState>`? I really don't understand why `RootState` should be, and the danger of not having

Comment: this solution is not even really typescript, as it uses `any` all the way

Comment: Right: `any` as the second parameter should be replaced by your actual `rootState` definition, or `Record<string, never>` if you don't have one.

Also, one can add `type` in the `import` line to help the compiler, like this: `import type { GetterTree, MutationTree, ActionTree } from "vuex"`

Comment: For a more extensive example have a look at this https://codeburst.io/vuex-and-typescript-3427ba78cfa8 BlogPost I found; Same example including couple example modules.

Comment: Hi folks, do you know in which part of the documentation is this info? I cannot find it, thanks in advance.